# How to use ngrok in conjuction with Okta with Android Emulator

Tags: android-emulator, single-sign-on, saml, okta, ngrok

I am testing SSO with okta. I am trying to login to okta using an Android Emulator. For me to be able to hit my local host from the emulator I used ngrok. Now i am able to access the local host from ngrok provided url "https://xxxx.ngrok.io/". I can get to the okta screen but when I login to okta it does not render the page but throws errors according to following saml settings on OKTA

**I have the following SAML settings on OKTA**

```
Single Sign On URL : https://localhost:port/signin-saml
Recipient URL : https://localhost:port/signin-saml
Destination URL : https://localhost:port/signin-saml
Audience Restriction : https:/localhost:port/saml
```

**I get the following error**

```
Webpage not available
The webpage at https://localhost:port/sigin-saml could not be loaded because
net:ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

**I tried changing the saml settings to the following in Okta**

```
 Single Sign On URL : https://xxxx.ngrok.io/signin-saml
 Recipient URL : https://xxxx.ngrok.io/signin-saml
 Destination URL : https://xxxx.ngrok.io/signin-saml
 Audience Restriction : https://xxxx.ngrok.io/saml
```

**I get back the following error,**

```
Exception: SAML Response has invalid Destination
```

I am not sure how i can use the ngrok url to redirect to android emulator.

Thank you!!